# AJAX Request fails because of file_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-get-contents

I'm doing a fun project by myself, which involves getting the HTML source from another web (from a different domain) and getting some info of it.

In my first steps I just made everything in PHP which worked perfectly fine, but now I'm trying to make it better with jQuery so the page works dynamically.

The thing is that my Ajax request fails whenever it reaches the "file_get_contents" call (which is the one that gives me the html source of the url).

The JS part:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getImage.php',
            data: {referencia: $("#referencia").val()},
            success: function(data){
                var div = document.getElementById("print");
                alert(data);
                div.innerHTML = "<img src="+""+"/>"; //Not finished

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error");
            }
});
```

The server part:

```
<?php
    $ref = $_POST['referencia'];

    if(isset($_GET['referencia'])){
        $url = /*some external url concatened with the post data*/;

        $data = file_get_contents($url);

        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Some notes I can provide: 
    -Changing the type of the ajax to post will make it fail, even if you remove the "file_get_contents" line.
    -I also tried this kind of request with no luck (this one doesn't fails when reaching the "file_get_contents" line but when executing the function, it doesn't return anything, but I have tested it standalone without requests and works fine):

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    req.open("POST", "getImage.php", true);

    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            var div = document.getElementById("print");
            alert(req.responseText);
            div.innerHTML = "<img src="+""+"/>";
        }
    }

    req.send("referencia=" + encodeURIComponent($("#referencia").val()));
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ishegg Actually I don't get a specific error, it's just that the ajax request wont reach success if the file_get_contents line is executed

Comment: Test it without AJAX using PostMan

Answer (score 0):

My solution worked for me 100% 
ajax -> server.php -> creates temp.zip -> returns back in header -> deletes temp.zip -> downloads the file

server.php

```
    //...
    //ToDo Endforeach
    $zip->close();

    /* SOLUTION 1 without saving */

    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_file).'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");


    ob_end_flush();
    readfile($zip_file);//important this line
    unlink($zip_file);

    die();
    #...
```

XMLHttpRequest instead of AJAX call

```
jQuery('.custom_button').click(function (e) {

    var d = "http://example.com/example.pdf";

    var url = '/wp-admin/admin-post.php';
    var filename = 'test.zip';
    var params = 'action=files_download&custom_file_names='+d;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.onload = function() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
    };
    request.send(params);

});
```

if everything is ok you will be able to download the file via browser without saving it on server side. Designed was for WordPress.